# Hash table/map implementation without dynamic allocations

Tags: c++, c, embedded, hashmap, hashtable

Does anyone know of a C/C++ hash table/map implementation that **does not** dynamically allocate memory?  I'm working on an embedded system that has no standard library & no heap (unless I want to write/port one).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to find a heap allocation implementation for embedded than a hash/map with no dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: If you can always free the allocated memory in the exactly opposite order of its allocation (e.g. `alloc a,b,c`, `free c,b,a`), your memory/heap manager can be as simple as a few dozen of lines of code implementing a stack data structure.

Comment: It _might_ be easier to implement a heap, but if this is the only thing I need it for, it might not be.  And a stack memory store means I wouldn't be able to remove items out of order, which might be an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The terms you're looking for are "Open addressing" or "closed hashing".
See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Hash_Tables#Open_addressing
and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing

Don't know a specific implementation, though. Sorry.

Comment: Good links though, they might come in helpful.

Comment: Actually, the pretty pictures in that article made me realize, I could also do chaining if I implemented a freelist from an store of nodes (probably just a static array).  But I do like the cache coherency of linear-probing open-addressing.